# Java: Logout functionality with servlet and cache control

Tags: java, security, servlets, logout

The below code is my servlet. I have used the `doFilter()` for cache control and the `doPost()` to invalidate the session and redirect to the login page. The back button problem still persists. Can somebody tell what I'm doing wrong? And please let me know the reason before you downvote!
Thanks in advance.

```
 public class LogoutServlet extends HttpServlet implements Servlet, Filter{

 @Override
  public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)   throws IOException, ServletException {

       HttpServletResponse hsr = (HttpServletResponse) res;
       hsr.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
       hsr.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
       hsr.setDateHeader("Expires", 0); // Proxies.
      chain.doFilter(req, res);
   }

 @Override
  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

   }


 @Override
 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {


          HttpSession session = request.getSession(false); 
            session.invalidate();
            response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");

  }

  @Override
  public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
      throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't know how you did this: but there is no Title in this question and you cannot click it: http://puu.sh/4S524.png

Comment: The problem seems to be gone. Really strange.

Comment: Alright, any solution to my problem?

Comment: What is the back button problem that you are seeing? Once you invalidate session, all the protected URLs should redirect user to login page.

Comment: Redirection works fine. The problem is one can go back to the secure page even after logging out by pressing the back button. Just like the classic problem.

Comment: Right, but its just data view, the user cannot add/modify/delete !

Comment: What if it is a secure page?